# Download universal artifact from azure devops using cURL

Tags: azure, curl, azure-devops, azure-rest-api

I would like to download **universal/UPack** artifact from Azure devops artifactory. I am aware I can use Azure CLI but that means requirement to have Azure CLI installed, which is the very last resort.

I already achieved similar approach for maven artifacts but I am unable to figure out proper approach for the universal/UPack artifact.

Following code will get the latest version of maven artifact and download specific file in the package.

```
PKG_VERSION=$(curl -s -u $ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME:$ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/<ORGANISATION_NAME>/<PROJECT_ID>/_apis/packaging/feeds/<FEED_ID>/packages?packageNameQuery=<GROUP_NAME>:<ARTIFACT_ID>&api-version=6.0" | jq -r ".value[0].versions[0].normalizedVersion")

curl -u $ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME:$ARTIFACTORY_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN -o /app/boot.jar -L https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANISATION_NAME>/<PROJECT_ID>/_apis/packaging/feeds/<FEED_ID>/maven/<GROUP_NAME>/<ARTIFACT_ID>/$PKG_VERSION/<JAR_FILE_NAME>/content
```

Is there a way to do similar thing to universal/UPack, with one extra condition: download whole content of that package, not just single file.

Comment: It appears that you are using [Azure Artifacts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/devops/artifacts/) (as part of Azure DevOps). [JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) is a different product and "Azure DevOps Artifactory" is not a thing.

Comment: Other packages types (Maven, Npm, NuGet, Python) have documented "Download Package" APIs (e.g. [Maven - Download Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/maven/download-package?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) but Universal packages do not. The Azure DevOps REST API documentation has a history of being incomplete so it's hard to know if the missing API doesn't exist or is undocumented.

Comment: If the API is there, my guess is the endpoint is a `GET` on the URL `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}/upack/packages/{packageName}/versions/{packageVersion}/content?api-version=6.0`

Comment: The API [**Universal - Get Package Version**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/universal/get-package-version?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) just shows information about a specified Universal package version in the response body (generally is JSON content). It will not download the specified Universal package version. There is no documented REST API to download the Universal package from Azure Artifacts feed.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other package types in Azure Artifacts, the Universal type packages do not have an available "**`Download Package`**" REST API can be used. So, you cannot use curl command to call a REST API to download Universal packages.

Currently, the only available method to download Universal packages is using the '[**`az artifacts universal download`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#download-packages)' command.

---

If your projects really need a REST API for Universal packages can be called by curl command to download Universal packages, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.